# sorting a very large dataset in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have this vector and I would like to sort it.

`v1<-c(1,10,2,6,8,1,3,5,"a","ab","c","d","aa","abc","a a","a bc")`.

However the vector has both numeric and characters in it. So i need sorting numerically after that with the characters.
the code `library(gtools); mixedsort(v1)` solves the purpose exactly as required.

But I am applying it to a dataset of around 3million. So it isnt efficient and I need a code which processes it faster.

Solution should be like this.

```
> mixedsort(v1)
 [1] "1"    "1"    "2"    "3"    "5"    "6"    "8"    "10"   "a"    "a a"  "a bc" "aa"   "ab"   "abc"  "c"    "d"
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: `stringr::str_sort(v1, numeric = TRUE)` is two orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: R vectors can only hold a single atomic data type. I assume that everything was converted to a string? Exactly how long does it take to run this on your 3 million records? That's a big sort job that would take sometime with even "normal" sort methods let alone more complicated ones. Are you also trying to re-arrange all the rows in memory as well? What exactly are you timing?

Comment: @one `base::sort` will sort `"1", "10", "2"`. That's why I suggested  `stringr::str_sort` with `numeric = TRUE`.

Comment: mixedsort takes upto 12 min, sometimes 9 min. yes the sorted data is stored in an another object.

Comment: This is also pretty fast. It needs some extra care for NA coercion though. ```mixed_sort2 <- function(vec){
  numeric_sort <- sort(as.numeric(vec));character_sort <- sort(vec[is.na(as.numeric(vec))]);c(numeric_sort,character_sort)
}```

Comment: It took 1.30 secs for `stringr::str_sort` to sort a vector of length 3 million, with 10K numeric and the others character, all shuffled with `sample`.

Comment: In its defense, I'm sure the author of `mixedsort` never thought of it being used in a big-data context ...

Comment: The `mixedsort` function has this test case in it's help page: `Treatment <- c("Control", "Aspirin 10mg/day", "Aspirin 50mg/day", "Aspirin 100mg/day", "Acetomycin 100mg/day", "Acetomycin 1000mg/day")`. It handles the case where text and numbers are mixed within the same string. Most of the other proposed solutions where will have a different outcome with such input.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Curiously, this kludgy dplyr/readr approach is 27x faster than `mixedsort` and 3x faster than `stringr::str_sort`, so it's clear there is lots more room for doing this faster.

Since then, I have tried `mixed_sort2` from @one and it's typically a smidge faster. Faster still is to use `as.numeric` in my original approach, to get about 100x as fast as `mixedsort`.

```
# fake data, 3 million rows of characters and numbers
v1 <- sample(c(1:99, LETTERS), 3E6, replace = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
df_parse <- function(a) {
  data.frame(a) %>%
    mutate(num = readr::parse_number(a)) %>% # 4x faster if we use `as.numeric` instead
    arrange(num, a) %>%
    pull(a)
}
```

edit: added from the comments @one's

```
mixed_sort2 <- function(vec){   
  numeric_sort <- sort(as.numeric(vec))
  character_sort <- sort(vec[is.na(as.numeric(vec))])
  c(numeric_sort,character_sort)
}
```

and using the dplyr approach + as.numeric is even faster:

```
df_asnumeric <- function(a) {
  data.frame(a) %>%
    mutate(num = as.numeric(a)) %>%
    arrange(num, a) %>%
    pull(a)
}
```

---

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  gtools::mixedsort(v1),
  stringr::str_sort(v1, numeric = TRUE),
  df_parse(v1),
  mixed_sort2(v1),
  df_asnumeric(v1),
  times = 10, check = 'identical'
)

Unit: milliseconds
                                  expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
                 gtools::mixedsort(v1) 80676.6222 81825.6986 84672.9726 83671.3667 87335.5948 92225.717    10
 stringr::str_sort(v1, numeric = TRUE)  4309.6739  4327.6529  4371.6771  4373.5337  4411.2573  4450.610    10
                          df_parse(v1)   777.4925  1031.4233  1133.8790  1052.9858  1073.2195  1683.851    10
                       mixed_sort2(v1)  3505.1529  3539.8577  3747.5667  3613.3492  4033.8569  4141.554    10
                      df_asnumeric(v1)   619.2090   635.7193   812.5554   864.3629   908.5028  1026.983    10
```

Comment: let me test parse_arrange, i will write again regarding its efficiency in my data.

Comment: I am getting this warning. is this okay?
> head(df_asnumeric(v1))
[1] "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1"
Warning message:
There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
ℹ In argument: `num = as.numeric(a)`.
Caused by warning:
! NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: warnings received  for parse and mixed_sort2 aswell.

Comment: Yes, those are noting that the letters can’t be converted to a number and are outputting NA. Safe to disregard or silence those.

Comment: I think this answer (just from today) about [arrange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77203320/6382434) is pretty relevant here. It is implemented in C, whereas other functions are not.

Comment: *Maybe* a bit faster than `mix_sort2` but not as fast as `arrange` based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70081088/6382434) is `x <- as.numeric(v1); v1[order(x, 'is.na<-'(v1, !is.na(x)))]`

Comment: Have you checked if all 5 commands are producing exactly same results? i am concerned if it isnt different from mixedsort which I have been using in the past.

Comment: The parameter `check = 'identical'` confirms the output is identical for my fake data, but it's possible there could be edge cases in your real data that could vary.

Answer (score 1):

Actually creating and sorting a data frame shouldn't be necessary, and I think it's only be done because `dplyr::arrange` can't sort vectors.

So here solutions that `order` a vector. Fastest is using radix sort in `order` which is substantially faster than `data.table:::forder`. Also taken up solution based on *@GKi* in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77203172/sorting-a-very-large-dataset-in-r#comment136105229_77203454) but it's not faster. Note, that `order` defaults to shell sort, that's why `sort_mix2a` is much slower.

```
sort_mix1a <- \(x) {
  x[order(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x)), x, method='radix')]
}

sort_mix1b <- \(x) {
  x[data.table:::forder(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x)), x)]
}

sort_mix2a <- \(x) {
  xn <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x)); x[order(xn, 'is.na<-'(x, !is.na(xn)))]
}

sort_mix2b <- \(x) {
  xn <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x)); x[order(xn, 'is.na<-'(x, !is.na(xn)), method='radix')]
}
```

Interestingly, *dplyr* is still faster, the R Core and data.table teams should address this soon ;)

### Benchmark

```
Unit: milliseconds
         expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval   cld
   sort_mix1a  796.4311  808.3563  828.4779  818.5288  841.8603   998.3645   100 a    
   sort_mix1b 1054.7839 1099.0674 1126.6471 1113.2735 1141.4472  1370.3815   100  b   
   sort_mix2a 7706.4836 7966.5524 8117.0054 8085.4303 8227.1749 10014.5421   100   c  
   sort_mix2b  861.4405  878.0625  908.6411  897.3095  913.1498  1098.3292   100    d 
 df_asnumeric  700.7507  713.9117  739.8404  728.9298  754.2535   957.6034   100     e
```

---

*Benchmark code:*

```
set.seed(42)
v1 <- sample(c(1:99, LETTERS), 3E6, replace=TRUE)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  sort_mix1a=sort_mix1a(v1), 
  sort_mix1b=sort_mix1b(v1), 
  sort_mix2a=sort_mix2a(v1), 
  sort_mix2b=sort_mix2b(v1), 
  df_asnumeric=suppressWarnings(df_asnumeric(v1)), 
  check='identical', 
  times=100L)
system("Rscript --vanilla --verbose  ~/mixsort.R")
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the method in my old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70080294/sort-column-in-r-strings-first-alphabetically-then-numbers-numerically/70081088#70081088) to have first numbers and then characters.

You can use `as.numeric` to convert the string-numbers to numeric. As there are some characters you will get warnings from `as.numeric` what I suppress using `suppressWarnings`. Use this numeric and the string in `order` to sort the vector. Additionally `radix`sort could be selected which could increase the speed.

```
sort_mixGKi <- \(x) {
    x[order(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x)), x, method="radix")]
}

sort_mixGKi(v1)
# [1] "1"    "1"    "2"    "3"    "5"    "6"    "8"    "10"   "a"    "a a" 
#[11] "a bc" "aa"   "ab"   "abc"  "c"    "d"
```

Note that `gtools::mixedsort` will also handle cases where numbers and strings are mixed like `a1`.

---

Benchmark

```
library(dplyr)
df_asnumeric <- function(a) {  # @Jon Spring
  data.frame(a) %>%
    mutate(num = as.numeric(a)) %>%
    arrange(num, a) %>%
    pull(a)
}

set.seed(42)
v2 <- sample(c(1:99, LETTERS), 3E6, TRUE)

bench::mark(
  mixedsort = gtools::mixedsort(v2),
  df_asnumeric = suppressWarnings(df_asnumeric(v2)),
  sort_mixGKi = sort_mixGKi(v2)
)
#  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 mixedsort     54.8s  54.8s    0.0182    1.19GB     1.77     1    97      54.8s
#2 df_asnumeric  320ms  320ms      3.12     141MB    18.7      4    24      1.28s
#3 sort_mixGKi   289ms  292ms      3.43    57.2MB     1.14    15     5      4.38s
```

`sort_mixGKi` is in this case the fastest (188 compared to mixedsort, 1.1 compared to df_asnumeric) and allocates the lowest amount of memory.

Comment: Interesting that it runs faster for you here but seems to have have been comparable for @jay.sf -- hardware / R version difference?

Comment: @JonSpring Maybe it depends on if it is compiled and optimized for the used hardware or using a generic precompiled version or how many times there was a garbage collection?