# R, sorting a data.table with a given user input

Tags: r, data.table

This is my data.

```
dt<-as.data.table(matrix(data = sample(c(paste0(sample(letters, 9), 1:120), round(runif(5) * 100)), 120, replace = TRUE),nrow = 20,ncol = 6,byrow = FALSE))
```

All or some columns are either number, alphabets or mix of both.
I need to sort the the data based on input of which columns i.e. whether for only 1 column or 2 columns together or more.

lets assume this is the user input currently

```
fromexcel<-c("V1", "V2", "V3")
```

1. But the code needs to be such that it is dynamic and considers more columns if asked.
2. columns asked from user need not be ordered but can be `c("V5", "V1")` this way as well.

I have always used `gtools::mixedsort()` but anything else efficient is welcome.

this post can be referenced if you find this useful.
[sorting a very large dataset in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77203172/sorting-a-very-large-dataset-in-r?noredirect=1#comment136104081_77203172)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for `setorderv`? `setorderv(dt, fromexcel)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option:

```
dt[do.call(order, mget(fromexcel))]
```

But as r2evans explains in comments the *canonical* `data.table` way would be (this sorts the table in place):

```
setorderv(dt, fromexcel)
```

Comment: For the record: `data.table` will optimize the use of `order` in this case, so it is using the same mechanism internally as `setorderv(dt, fromexcel)`. (One should not confuse this with using base R's `order`, since from `?setorder`: *"Note that queries like ‘x[order(.)]’ are optimised internally to use ‘data.table’'s fast order"*.)

Comment: I do suggest, though, that including `setorderv(dt, fromexcel)` should be included as the `data.table`-canonical code as well. It results in the same speed and efficiency as `order(.)` but with a little code golf and perhaps clearer coding "intent".

Comment: Thanks Evans! Hope you are doing great.